# Why do i have the error must be of type array, string given, in Symfony 2.8 during composer update

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony-2.8

I try to install a 2.8 Symfony project but when I try to composer update or composer install the composer.json i have this message, do you know what can i do ? My php is 5.6.39

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.6.39"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "5.6.39",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "bmatzner/modernizr-bundle": "~2.7",
        "bmatzner/jquery-bundle": "~1.9",
        "bmatzner/foundation-bundle": "~5.3",
        "bmatzner/fontawesome-bundle": "4.*",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.4",
        "sendinblue/sendinblue-api-bundle": "^2.0",
        "ob/highcharts-bundle": "1.*",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.3",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "^0.12.3",
        "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "^2.2",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.6",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^0.17.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error i have everytime i try to do composer install or composer update :

```
> Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process::\__construct(): Argument #1 ($command) must be of type array, string given, called in /home/lucas/IBS/ibs-extanet/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php on line 455 and defined in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:143
> Stack trace:
> \#0 /home/lucas/IBS/ibs-extanet/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php(455): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process-\>\__construct()
> \#1 /home/lucas/IBS/ibs-extanet/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php(82): Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::executeBuildBootstrap()
> \#2 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(389): Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap()
> \#3 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(238): Composer\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher-\>executeEventPhpScript()
> \#4 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(119): Composer\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher-\>doDispatch()
> \#5 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(372): Composer\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher-\>dispatchScript()
> \#6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php(248): Composer\\Installer-\>run()
> \#7 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(298): Composer\\Command\\UpdateCommand-\>execute()
> \#8 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(1015): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command-\>run()
> \#9 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(299): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application-\>doRunCommand()
> \#10 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(336): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application-\>doRun()
> \#11 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(171): Composer\\Console\\Application-\>doRun()
> \#12 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(131): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application-\>run()
> \#13 /usr/bin/composer(84): Composer\\Console\\Application-\>run()
> \#14 {main}
> thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php on line 143
```

Yesterday i saw the error came when this par of the composer.json is played :

```
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
```

Especially the part :

```
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
```

Comment: That project requires `"php": "8.1.2"` and your version is `5.6.39`?

Comment: That problem sounds like one related to the command you call, not to Composer. Keep in mind that Symfony 2.8 is horribly outdated and might not be compatible with PHP 8.1

Comment: Yes the project require "php": "8.1.2" if i don't write this it makes an error, when i do php-v it's write 5.6.39 and in my project i have a .php-version with 5.6.39 in it.

Comment: "It makes an error" - which one? If you **really** use PHP 5.6, you should put it in your composer.json such that it installs compatible package. Otherwise, packages compatible with PHP 8.1 are installed, and these are most likely incompatible with PHP 5.6